# Instantiating a class and using properties makes app crash

Tags: ios, swift, class, object, instantiation

I'm building  a keyboard extension.
In my program I have a view controller(1) and a view(2) class which I use for a xib file .

1)

```swift
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "view1", bundle: nil)
        let objects = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
        view = objects[0] as? UIView
}
```

2. 

```swift
class View1: UIView {  

@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!
}
```

I wanted to instantiate the view class inside of my view controller so, following apple's documentation I did this:

```swift
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    let v1 = View1()
    let v2 = View2()
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to call inside of my view did load something like:

```swift
v1.someLabel.text = "something"
```

and I run my app, for some reasons it doesn't work and eventually crashes.

Important things: the views are connected to two different .xib files and I'm working on a custom keyboard extension.

I'm sure I'm missing something in the instantiation but I can't find out what it is, I see other developers on git hub doing exactly the same as I do but running their apps gives no problem...  So what am I missing out? If you can please send me more documentation about it as well...

**Edit:**
In both my view classes I'm doing the following to initialize them:

```swift
class View1: UIView {  
@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!
  init(label: UILabel, button: UIButton) {
        self.someLabel = label
        self.someButton = button
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 330, height: 200))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

But then in my main view controller, when i call `let v1 = View1()`, it becomes:

```
let v1 = View1(coder: NSCoder)
```

And I'm having a hard time figuring out what to put in the parameter field

Comment: You need to post more code - enough so someone can duplicate your issue. From what you've posted? It looks good. BUT... where are you trying to set the text? It really gets down to understanding *both* the view controller *and* view lifecycles. Mostly, what are you doing in `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and inside your views? Also, what kind of error are you getting? Is it possible that `v1` isn't yet in your view hierarchy?

Comment: Hi, actually my code is exactly what I posted for the important things I need. View1 and 2 only contain a bunch of labels and buttons, nothing easy. In my view did load I only posted what I already said in my question... The other code I wrote isn't related to this question

Comment: Sorry to disagree with you, but you haven't posted enough code. If I simply copied/pasted what you've posted into a brand new project, it wouldn't work! (Nor would it build.) I'm trying to help you - I really think it's the sequence (or life cycle) of what you are doing with your two views and one view controller that matter. Like these others on GitHub, it's pretty basic to instantiate two views - even one with a `UITextField` - and initialize a value in it. So yeah, I think you must being doing a simple thing wrong. It always helps to have a second pair of eyes... but without more code?

Comment: Sure, I got it now, I omitted some important things such as that the 2 views are connected to a xib file and that I'm working on a keyboard extension. Furthermore (this is not important but still...) I needed labels, not textfields ahaha. By the way I figured out I'm not initializing the View. I'll update my code in a few moments again in order to show how I'm doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

1. Go to your xib file, in the file's owner section set the custom class on View1; As per the view section, set the custom class to UIView;
2. In your `class View1: UIView` add a view outlet from your xib file ie:

```swift
@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
```

3. Paste this in your `class View1: UIView`

```swift
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("view1", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
       //Add any other setup here
    }
```

4. Now create another xib file, make sure it's file's Owner is `KeyboardViewController`. Add an UIView to it and make sure its class is of type View1.
5. Now go to class `KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController` and link the view of type View1 in your code. Right under it write `weak var v : View1!`
6. In `viewDidLoad()`you can eventually write `view = View1()`

You're done!

Answer (score 0):

If it's crash, I think that your `UITextField` in your `View1` is null. This field is init in your class or it refers to a `UINib` or `UIStoryboard` ?

To fix this, try init child elements in your custom `UIView` as well.

Comment: It's a nib and it's just the view (connected to the nib which i use in a keyboard) that crashes, I forgot to add that in my question... Plus I made aother mistake (not so important I guess but still...): I use labels not text fields ahah. I was trying a few moments ago to initialize the view but I guess I'm doing that wrong now, so I'll post an edit IN A  few moments

Comment: call `init(label: UILabel, button: UIButton) ` instead of this function `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) `

Comment: If you mean I only have to declare the first one instead of the second one, it's not possible, deleting the required init ives an error. In the ViewController where I istantiate the objects instead I'm not calling any of the functions but since i have to use the required init, I havve to add a parameter in 'let v1 = View1()' and the parameter is coder: NSCoder, I don't know what to do in this situation